# LoopBack: How do I use PUT to replace an entry

Tags: rest, loopbackjs

I struggle a bit with a basic PUT in a LoopBack project, but I cannot find any information about my problem. If use PUT to add an entry everything works fine, I just pass my data and there is a new entry in the database. Now I want to replace an entry, as described in the documentation for PUT (I am using the API explorer for my tests). My idea was to pass an 'id' (in addition to the changed data) and LoopBack would replace the corresponding entry. But that does not work, I get the error:

```
The `Model` instance is not valid. Details: `id` can't be set
```

How can I use PUT to replace an entry?

Comment: Are you passing the id as part of the model payload or are you passing it as a parameter?

Comment: I am passing it as part of the model payload.

Comment: Uhmm.. could it be a type issue? [In this example](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/PersistedModel-REST-API.html) they use `{"id": "98", "name": "L4", ...` Maybe you are passing an int instead of a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` property in the PUT payload should be optional.  If you're using the standard Loopback model CRUD endpoints that are set up during model generation you have two options:

1. Using the PUT `/ModelName/{id}` option where LB will find the model instance based on the query parameter passed into the URL.
2. Using the POST `/ModelName/{id}/replace` endpoint.  This endpoint will replace all attributes of a given model instance based on the `id` that's passed into the URL.

Passing in the `id` property in the payload of the request is optional for both endpoints.  Loopback will find the model instance based on the `id` param of the URL.